# How can I overcome Run-time error '1004' when trying to sort my data?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am filtering a big set of data. As part of the process, I am trying to sort a range of cells either by ascending or descending order given a certain condition.

I have researched a few options regarding how to sort. I am struggling to understand the parameters.

```
If Abs(Worksheets("Points").Cells(i, 4).Value - Worksheets("Points").Cells(i - 1, 5).Value) > _
Abs(Worksheets("Points").Cells(j + 1, 4).Value - Worksheets("Points").Cells(i, 5).Value) Then
    'Test to see whether logically the User moved from
    'the previous Sensors to the time stamp Sensors (Decending) or
    'from the time stamp Sensors to the next Sensor (Acending).
    'This If is used to determine whether sorting must happen
    'in an Acending or Decending order
    'Time MUST be in date format!!!!!

    Worksheets("Trips").Range(Cells(1, 23), Cells(k, 27)).Sort _
    Key1:=Worksheets("Trips").Range(Cells(1, 27)), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
Else
    Worksheets("Trips").Range(Cells(1, 23), Cells(k, 27)).Sort _
    Key1:=Worksheets("Trips").Range(Cells(1, 27)), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Key1:=Worksheets("Trips").Range(Cells(1, 27))` to `Key1:=Worksheets("Trips").Columns(27)`

You were telling it to sort on a single cell, the first row in column 27.